# DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL in react

Tags: reactjs

Suhu/Guru, help me

```
componentDidMount() {
axios
  .get(API_URL + "products")
  .then((res) => {
    const menus = res.data;
    this.setState({ menus });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

}

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.menus);
    return (
```

and my API in Local Server

```
export const API_URL = "http://localhost:3004";
```

and thi's my problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6SXZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result URL is `"http://localhost:3004products"` you must to append '/' after API_URL

Comment: oh thank's brother

Comment: if it corrent answer, put the corrent answer button please

Answer (score 0):

May be It is making request as "http://localhost:3004products", add '/' in-between URL.

Either add '/' before product or behind URL of API_URL

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(API_URL + "/products")   // Change
      .then((res) => {
        const menus = res.data;
        this.setState({ menus });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```